# how to move a div next to another div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sidebar that starts from the top, but can't get it to be on the top. I can only align it with the other divs.

I do not know how I can get it to be at the top. I have tried random codes like, the clear and overflow but none work. I also tried the position absolute and relative, but it messes up the other content.

```css
/* main content */

.container {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.hightlight {
  margin: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
}

#teaser-title {
  background-color: #555;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 15px 5px 0px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Geometos;
  width: 855px;
}


/* sidebar content */

.sidebar {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 1.00);
  height: 100%;
  width: 419px;
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  margin: 5px 15px 15px 0px;
}


/* recent content */

.one,
.two {
  margin: 5px;
}

.postOne {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 1.00);
  margin: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.postTwo {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 1.00);
  margin: 5px 15px 15px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="teaser-title">
  <span>>> Highlights</span>
</div>
<div class="hightlight">
  <img src="images/thumb-1.jpg" width="855" height="400" />
</div>

<div id="teaser-title">
  <span>>> Blog</span>
</div>

<div class="postOne">
  <div class="one">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/placeholder.jpeg" width="405" height="200" class="top-img" alt="image" />
      <h5>>>Post Title</h5>
      <p>content goes here</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="postTwo">
  <div class="two">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/placeholder.jpeg" width="405" height="200" class="top-img" alt="image" />
      <h5>>>Post Title</h5>
      <p>content goes here</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <p>content here</p>

</div>
```

Comment: `Float` is a **very** poor **and outdated** method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/), especially `flexbox` and `CSS-Grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:
First, as @Paulie_D mentioned in comments float is old and I have also used flexbox
in this code.
Basically just used flex-flow to control the flow of elements

Html Code:

```
<div class="firstDiv">
  <div>
    <div id="teaser-title">
      <span>>> Highlights</span>
    </div>
    <div class="hightlight">
      <img src="images/thumb-1.jpg" width="855" height="400" />
    </div>
    
    <div id="teaser-title">
      <span>>> Blog</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="postOne">
      <div class="one">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/placeholder.jpeg" width="405" height="200" class="top-img" alt="image" />
          <h5>>>Post Title</h5>
          <p>content goes here</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="postTwo">
      <div class="two">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="images/placeholder.jpeg" width="405" height="200" class="top-img" alt="image" />
          <h5>>>Post Title</h5>
          <p>content goes here</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>content here</p> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Css Code:

```
.firstDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: column-reverse;
}
.sidebar {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255);
  border: 2px solid rgba(193, 193, 193, 1.00);
  height: 100%;
  width: 419px;
  margin: 5px 15px 15px 0px;
}
```